# GCC: how to find why an object file is not discarded

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, ld

I have an executable which links to a big .a archive that contains lots of functions. The executable only uses a small fraction of the functions in this archive, but for some reason it pulls everything from it and ends up being very big.
My suspicion is that some of the functionality that the executable is using somehow references something it shouldn't and that causes everything else to be pulled.
Is it possible to make gcc tell me what reference causes a specific symbol to be added in the executable? Why else can this happen?

I've tried using `--gc-sections` with no effect.
I've tried using `--version-script` to make all the symbols in the executable local with no effect
I'm not interested in `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` since it is while object files I want to discard, not functions.
Other answers mention `-why_live` but that seem to be implemented only for darwin and I am in linux x86_64

Comment: Do you *know* that the functions you use doesn't use anything else in the library? It can be chained you know, you use one function which uses another two functions which uses another four etc.

Comment: You can simulate what the linker does applying `nm -g` to the object files you list on the command line, and then to the object files extracted from the archive library you're worried about, and see what comes from where.  It'll be painful, but could be done.  You need to know the defined and undefined global references.  If there's C++ code, it could get a tad fraught (the names will be long, but string matching is still the main requirement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-Wl,-M` to pass `-M` to the linker, causing it to print a link trace. This will show you the reasons (or at least the first-found reason) for every object file that gets linked from an archive.

Comment: This worked in helping me find the bad cross reference. Thanks!